# Check elements contrast automatic

Tags: selenium, testing, wcag

Would like to know if anyone has automated contrast testing of elements to support WCAG-standards. I'd like to have a test that breaks if the styling is not suitable for people with reduced vision abilities.

I'm currently testing my website using selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Tenon.io and the Tenon API?

From the page at https://tenon.io/getcode.php:

> Tenon Selenium Example
>
> Another one by Justin Stockton, this repo shows some simple examples of how to perform Tenon assertions as part of a set of functional tests driven by Webdriver.io.

Points to a repo at https://github.com/poorgeek/tenon-selenium-example:

> This repo shows some simple examples of how to perform Tenon assertions as part of a set of functional tests driven by Webdriver.io.